# Макет из трех колонок, выровненный по центру страницы с резиновой центральной колонкой

Tags: html, css

Собственно в заголовке и есть вопрос - можно ли это сделать без использования таблиц?

Comment: да, две боковые же фиксированы ?

Comment: [на новых браузерах](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) можно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/KFYhd/4/)
[на чуть менее новых](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) [`display: table`;](http://jsfiddle.net/KFYhd/5/)

Comment: Еще можно спозиционировать абсолютно левую и правую колонки, если позволяет задача. И еще flex box можно, если позволяет кроссбраузерность.

Answer (score 1):

Кому как нравится, я люблю делать так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/3Xhuw/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/KFYhd/7/